# Issue with obtaining the value of the checked radio button in a group?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please take a look at my [test page](http://www.completeinsight.co/creative-media/christmas/personalised-corporate-christmas-cards-2011/), my issue is to do with finding the value of the selected radio button in the "Select picture" group.

On loading I have used the following code:

```
var currentImageFile = $("input:radio[name=selectedImage]:checked").val();
```

which picks up the default image for the "Selected picture" div on the left. So far so good.

Now the problem is when a "Select picture" radio button is subsequently clicked my event code:

```
$("input:radio[name=selectedImage]").click(function() {     
  currentImageFile = $(this).val();
  alert($(this).val());  
});
```

(the alert is for testing only) returns no value at all!

The HTML is pretty straight forward:

```
<li><div class="xmasImage rounded" rel="http://www.completeinsight.co/resources/xmasHR/56269.jpg">
    <img class="rounded" src="http://www.completeinsight.co/resources/xmasLR/56269_p.jpg" width="65" height="65" border="0" alt="56269" />
    <div class="imageSelect"><input type="radio" name="selectedImage" value="56269">
        &nbsp;<label for="selectedImage">56269</label>
    </div>
</div></li>
```

I am missing the obvious??

Comment: Does it work any better if you use the change() event instead of click?

Comment: Did you correct this? Works fine in Chrome, FF, and IE.

Comment: @SurrealDreams: it shouldn't, although change() would probably be preferable anyway. click() will fire even if the radio button is already selected; change() will not.

Comment: @Tyran67: Code seems fine to me. Is your jQuery code is inside a `$(document).ready(function() {...});` wrapper?

Comment: Hey Tyran, see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vHkTG/). Clicking the radio button there is working, so there may be other things going on in your page. Even [adding additional radio buttons](http://jsfiddle.net/vHkTG/1/), everything still works. Can you perhaps update the jsFiddle with an example that's failing? Also, does the alert return no value, or does it not fire at all?

Comment: Is this fixed?  If not, perhaps more detail. You have not actually stated what is going wrong or what your expectations of behavior are. Your test page is not helpful.

Comment: @Dan-Short - sorry about that I was in quite a rush on Friday. I haven't come across [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vHkTG/) before, pretty useful! I have updated it with all the relevant code to show the full workings. From what I can see it looks like the variable 'currentImageFile" is being wiped or not able to be read by the 'imageswap' function I suspect this is due to my lack of understanding of variable usage? The weird thing is it DOES work in Chrome, but Firefox and IE go belly up (latest Firefox, IE8/7 compatiable)

Comment: @Dan I have updated jsfiddle, sorry still getting used to the comment markups!

Comment: @Jason, updated Dan's jsfiddle page

Comment: When I click on your test page in Safari (linked to from your question) everything alerts correctly.

Comment: It just falls over in IE and my version of Firefox. Frustrating. Looking at the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vHkTG/) code is there anywhere I can make improvements for cross broswer compatability?? When I click in IE an 'undefined' value is returned but Chrome is perfectly happy!

Comment: This is really odd now. I have added an 'onClick' in Dreamweaver thinking I could obtain the radio button's value that way, but it still returns as undefined. Has anyone come across this???? As already mentioned Chrome works a treat but Firefox and IE8 both seem unable to access the button correctly.

Comment: Ok, can anyone explain this. If I add an empty alert(); BEFORE the 'currentImageFile' line in the function IT THEN WORKS IN IE?????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var currentImageFile = '';
            $('#ImageSelection').find("input:radio[name=selectedImage]").click(function () {
                currentImageFile = $(this).val();
                alert($(this).val());
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="ImageSelection">
        <li>
            <div class="xmasImage rounded" rel="http://www.completeinsight.co/resources/xmasHR/56269.jpg">
                <img class="rounded" src="http://www.completeinsight.co/resources/xmasLR/56269_p.jpg"
                    width="65" height="65" border="0" alt="56269" />
                <div class="imageSelect">
                    <input type="radio" name="selectedImage" value="56269">
                    &nbsp;<label for="selectedImage">56269</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="xmasImage rounded" rel="http://www.completeinsight.co/resources/xmasHR/56270.jpg">
                <img class="rounded" src="http://www.completeinsight.co/resources/xmasLR/56270_p.jpg"
                    width="65" height="65" border="0" alt="56270" />
                <div class="imageSelect">
                    <input type="radio" name="selectedImage" value="56270">
                    &nbsp;<label for="selectedImage">56270</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```